# Can I build a docker image from an existing database container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker. I am using docker compose to manage containers.

My goal is to have a database container persists or not persist data, which can be pulled by other developers without many manual steps (pg_dump and pg_store etc) to run their dev environment locally.

I want to know if I can build a docker image of a snapshot of a database (postgres). Is this possible? If not, what is the recommended way to do this with docker?

Thank you.

Comment: A docker image is just a bunch of files.  You can put anything you want in there.

Comment: get a container running your DB into a state you want it, and then run `docker commit container_id` and you can push that container to a place where your colleagues can use, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 6):

In docker you can save data in two places basically:

1. Inside the container (default)
2. A volume

The database containers are configured to save data in volumes, because in this way the data can survive a container deletion. Also it is faster. When you create an image from a container, the data from volumes won't get into.

But you can create a database container which have an *archive* script, which will execute `pg_dump` or `cp` and save the result in any directory outside any volume mounted. So the data will be inside the container and can fly out to an image.

Then use `docker commit <container id>` to save the changes to a new image. Tag the new image `docker tag <image id> registry/postgres:withdata` and do a `docker push`.

In the `Dockerfile` include a script which after the database startup, check if it is empty. If it is empty restore it using `pg_restore` or `cp` from the container.

Well it is only an idea to route you a little. It is possible, just require a little work.

Regards